# UITabBarItem not showing icon on first launch after installation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a UITabViewController inside a UINavigationController. As you can see on the image bellow the tab icons are set to system default "favorite" and "download" icons and they show properly when where looking in the storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

One of the tabs has a collection view and the other has a web view with a status bar.

The problem is that when I deploy the app (to the simulator or a real device), the first time it opens the tab bar icon from the tab which is unselected doesn't show.

[image: Error image]

After i close and reopen the app the icon shows fine. The same thing happens if I select the tab.

[image: Error after reopen]

How can I make the image appear correctly the first open after installation? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Xcode 6 with iOS 8.2

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the source of your problem, but you're not supposed to embed a tab bar controller in a navigation controller. From Apple's docs: "Before creating a tab bar interface, you need to decide how you intend to use a tab bar interface. Because it imposes an overarching organization on your data,you should use one only in these specific ways:

Install it directly as a window’s root view controller.
Install it as one of the two view controllers in a split view interface. (iPad only)
Present it modally from another view controller.
Display it from a popover. (iPad only)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the **selected image of the particular Tab bar item** of the view controller just delete that selected image and give them ***programatically*** then connect the segue of the tab bar controller to relationship segue then it will work. And then you are supposed to use Tab bar --> Navigation controller --> view controller